# How to bind Bootstrap list selector for spring mvc 3.2.2?

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

How can I bind the following Bootstrap list selector given the following? I have the select list populated fine from passed in view model from controller to index.jsp. However, there seems to be a lot of variation on binding.

```
class viewModel {
  List<String> theList;      // <- populated in my GET controller code
  String selectedListItem;   // <- trying to figure out how to get selected list item?
  o o o
  // assume get/set
}
```

index.jsp:

(I get the postback fine on the submit button click and I can access the viewmodel but just need to figure out how I can get the selected item from the list.)

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="myController/indexSubmit" method="post">
        <select class="form-control" placeholder=".input-medium" height>
            <c:forEach items="${viewModel.gettheList()}" var="item" varStatus="count"> 
                <option value="${count.index}">${item }</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>   
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Submit</button>   
    </form>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="indexSubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String indexSubmit(@ModelAttribute("viewModel") viewModel viewModel, ModelMap model) {
    String item = viewModel.getselectedListItem(); // <- How can I pass this in?
    System.out.println("Selected Item: " + item);
    return "myController/index";  // <- want to add as query param: ?item=theItem  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create special class to bind list of elements. Simplest example of binding select with controller:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {  
    List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
    listString.add("hello");
    listString.add("world");
    listString.add("from");
    listString.add("Belarus");
    model.addAttribute("listString", listString);
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@RequestParam String selectedString, Model model) {
    System.out.println(selectedString);
    return "index";
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="${home}/test" method="post">
    <select name="listString" class="form-control">
        <c:forEach items="${listString}" var="item" varStatus="count"> 
            <option value="${count.index}">${item}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Submit</button>   
</form>
```

With that code after submitting form you will see selected items indexes in console.

If you want to transport also initial list (listItem) you can make another select with all items selected and attribute `multiple="multiple"` and set its style to display: none; After this declare another param `@RequestParam List<String> listString` and you'll get your initial array of strings.

About adding param:

```
return "myController/index";  // <- want to add as query param: ?item=theItem
```

You can't pass parameter that way. Thats because you return **name of view** (tiles of simply name of jsp), but not url. If you want to go to url with param you can make:

```
return "forward:/index?item=theItem";
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again for the great example: QQ1-How could I get the returned string that was selected instead of the index value?  QQ2: How could I assign name="listString" where listString was part of a model view instead of a barebones string passed in? So: class mv {public String listString}?

Comment: A1: to get string value instead of index: <option value="${item}">${item}</option> A2: it is quite different situation. Try to look at jsp in this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm but instead of form:input use form:select. Look at this tutorial to understand spring form tags better: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html